# Exchange 2007 Read-Only permissions to shared accounts

Tags: permissions, exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, exchange

I have Exchange 2007 running on SBS 2008. There are several accounts created which are shared by departments.

In the shared email users keep track of the status of jobs by moving them to Sub Directories in the mailbox. 
I would like to be able to grant other people in the company read-only access to the mailbox to allow them to check on the status of jobs but not have permissions to change anything.

I have tried setting the permissions in Outlook for the account but most of the time it doesn't seem to work, and when it does work it only shares the Inbox not the sub directories.

I have tried downloading the PFDAVAdmin.EXE to manage the permissions but my desktops are all Windows 7 & My server is SBS 2008 so this tool cannot run. I tried running it in XP mode but it was not able to connect properly.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=635BE792-D8AD-49E3-ADA4-E2422C0AB424&displaylang=en

I have also considered setting up a main enabled public folder but I use the pop3 connector for exchange so in order for that to work I would have to setup an additional account for each user to forward the email to the public folder as POP3 connector can't deliver directly to public folders that I know of.

Any ideas...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I made is when I was connecting to the server I put the IP instead of the FQDN of the server. Putting the FQDN fixed the issue